# Same table name for two schemas on the same tablespace

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, is it possible to store in one tablespace the data for two tables that share the same name but are defined for different users (schemas)?

Or maybe I need to create separate tablespace per user if there might be a name clash?

I cannot easily check it for myself, as I dont' have any instance with proper privilliges available currently.

Comment: You mean oracle users? or your application users? because oracle users have his own schema and you can have the same table name in different schemas

Comment: Yes, I mean Oracle users i.e. schemas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you have 2 users (schemas) so yes you can create 2 tables with same name with different users for example `create table user1.tab1 ...`  and `create table user2.tab1 ...`

> I need to create separate tablespace per user if there might be a name
>   clash

let me do some explanation ..in oracle you already have several users , for example system users that as it obvious have high privileges then you have/create other users that have specific privilege , every users has his own objects, his own tables , procedure... and this users and its objects normally and can resides in one datafiles which the datafile resides in the tablespace.

Comment: +1. As long as the tables are being created under different schemas, there is no problem with them sharing the same tablespace. "Table 1" under Schema A is logically separate from "Table 1" under Schema B.